# Transform a "Regex" string to actual Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to pass a regular expression in a validation function in my code that can only be set by an administrator in a back office platform as a string (e.g. `'/^(?:\d{8}|\d{11})$/'`). After it is passed I need to take this string and transform it into an actual javascript regex in order to use it.

```
const validator = (regex, value) => {
  if (value && regex.test(value)) {
    return 'Yeah!!';
  }
  return null;
};
```

So I need this `'/^(?:\d{8}|\d{11})$/'` to be like this `/^(?:\d{8}|\d{11})$/`.

Comment: The first result of _"javascript string to regex"_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a regex with the `RegExp` method ([documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)):

> The **`RegExp`** constructor creates a regular expression object for matching text with a pattern.

```
const regex2 = new RegExp('^(?:\\d{8}|\\d{11})$');
console.log(regex2); // /^(?:\d{8}|\d{11})$/
```

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work.
Check the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/MavrosGatos/p96txL7d/3/

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and I've edited my answer. When using RegExp, you don't include the forward slashes in the string. Also, you must escape the backslashes. Try it now.

Comment: _"Also, you must escape the backslashes"_ - That's not the only character you have to escape.

Comment: @Andreas yes it is, backslashes are the only characters with special meaning in strings in js (we are not talking about escaping the regex tokens here, just the string so that it's a valid string)

Technically you'd also need to escape your string delimiters if any within the string but that's common sense

Also If that string is coming from an input then it's already escaped

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate the RegExp class and use it in two ways:

**First:**

```
new RegExp('<expression>').test(...)
```

**Second:**

```
/<expression>/.test(...)
```

Both ways will create an RegExp instance.

**When to use one over the other?**

Using the new RegExp way you can pass variables to the expression, like that:

```
new RegExp('^abc' + myVar + '123$');
```

Which you **can't** do using the second way.